# How do I get the aggregate number of a variable against another variable in R? Both these variables are non-numeric

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have this dataset, and I am trying to create a new variable (n_commitments) that will give me an aggregate number of paragraphs per country. I know this is super basic but I have somehow been stuck for an hour now. I think it is something to do with the fact that both variables are character classes and I want a numeric as an output.

Please help so I can finally move on. Thank you.

```
      structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), paragraphs = c("The representative of Afghanistan confirmed that his Government would ensure the transparency of its ongoing privatization programme. He stated that his Government would provide reports to WTO Members on developments in its privatisation programme, periodically and upon request, as long as the programme would be in existence, and along the lines of the information already provided to the Working Party during the accession process. The Working Party took note of this commitment. ", 
"The representative of Afghanistan confirmed that from the date of accession, State-trading enterprises (including State-owned and State-controlled enterprises, enterprises with special or exclusive privileges, and unitary enterprises) in Afghanistan would make any purchases or sales, which were not for the Government's own use or consumption, solely in accordance with commercial considerations, including price, quality, availability, marketability, transportation and other conditions of purchase or sale. He further confirmed that these State trading enterprises would afford the enterprises of other Members adequate opportunity, in accordance with customary business practice, to compete for participation in purchases from or sales to Afghanistan's State enterprises. The Working Party took note of these commitments.  "
)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

    Columns: 8
$ country            <chr> "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanis…
$ category           <chr> "State Ownership and Privatization; State-Trading Entities", "State Ownership and Pr…
$ paragraphs         <chr> "The representative of Afghanistan confirmed that his Government would ensure the tr…
$ year_complete      <int> 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, …
$ year_start         <int> 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, …
$ accession_duration <int> 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, …
$ wto                <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
$ n_commitments      <chr> "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", …
```

Comment: Are you looking for Please don't just post screenshots of data - post sample data as copy/pasteable text to create a minimal example.

Comment: @GregorThomas Apologies! Is this better?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't super clear. `dput()` is the nicest way as it is copy/pasteable and includes class and structure info. Something like `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows. But also feel free to limit the columns, if the only columns relevant to your question are paragraphs and country, `dput(your_data[1:5, c("country", "paragraphs")])` is more minimal, so nicer.

Comment: Lastly, please share the output you expect for the sample input. When you say the *"aggregate number of paragraphs per country"*, is that the same as the row count per country? I.e., is each row of your data a unique paragraph? Or do we need to count the number of unique paragraphs per country? Or something else?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for your comments! I tried "dput" but I don't think it looks cleaner than "glimpse", maybe I'm just doing something wrong. As for the output, each row of the data is a unique paragraph. I want to group the paragraph data by country, and get the aggregate number of unique paragraphs per country. If that makes sense.

Comment: No, the `dput()` doesn't **look** any cleaner than `glimpse`, but if I copy/paste the `dput()` into R it will create a replica of your data for me and I can run code on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to count the unique paragraphs by country:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarize(n_unique_paragraphs = n_distinct(paragraphs))
```

If, as you say, *"each row of the data is a unique paragraph"*, then we can simplify and just count rows:

```
df %>% group_by(country) %>%
  summarize(n = n())
```

There's also built-in utility function for this:

```
df %>% count(country)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For your patience as well 